# converting a string of json data into html with angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I have an API response of html. I want that converted into html instead of just text. How can i go about this?

Example: response is

```
   $scope.response = response.data
```

And in the html

```
    {{response.content}}
```

If the response.content is < p>this is a response< /p>,

How do i make angular respond with 'this is a response', not the above?

Comment: You can do it with `<p ng-bind-html="response"></p>` by using [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize)

Comment: Be careful, however. Angular prevents rendering HTML for (very valid) security reasons. If response.content contains data that can be entered by users, you make your site susceptible to cross site scripting attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ng-bind-html and inject ngSanitize in your module like below :

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.response={};
     $scope.response={content : "<p><h1>This is response<h1></p>"};
    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p ng-bind-html="response.content"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```